# How to get different values for same ID in dataframe. And replace any of that different value for the same ID

Tags: r

I am dealing with data frames and have a dataset let's say

```
ID   Name
1     aaa
1     aaa.
1     aaa
2     ccc
3     111.
3     333
3     111
3     111
```

I want the longest string for each ID
Output.

```
1     aaa.
2     ccc
3     111.
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
    Name = c("aaa", "aaa.", "aaa", "ccc", "111.", "333", "111", "111")
    ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-8L)
  )
```

Comment: Not sure how this is a duplicate. Try `library(dplyr);dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.max(nchar(Name)))`

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(nchar(Name)==max(nchar(Name)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Name 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 aaa. 
2     2 ccc  
3     3 111.
```

With `base`(might need some filtering to match Name):

```
aggregate(.~ID,dat,function(x) x[which.max(x)])
  ID Name
1  1 aaa.
2  2  ccc
3  3  333
```

Using `slice` and `dplyr` as suggested by @Wil:

```
dat %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
slice(which.max(nchar(Name)))
```

Comment: Thoughts on `dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.max(nchar(Name)))`? I don't have enough rep to answer a question marked as duplicate.

Comment: I can also not answer a duplicate but had placed an answer before it was marked as a duplicate. I simply undeleted it. I'm not sure but `slice` should suffice here(I think) as that's what `filter` is doing anyways.

Comment: Thank you @Will and NelsonGon. I appreciate your effort. This solution works for me with filter

Comment: @YagneshJani Welcome. Glad it worked for you.